# inter-arrival time between customers to a restaurant with an exponential distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

The interarrival time between customers to a restaurant is given to follow Exp(0.1) in minutes, (including the time between their opening and arrival of the 1st customer)  what is the probability that the first 5 customers arrive within 40 min?

I come with this result:
$\lambda = 40*0.1$
$\Pr(X=k) = (\lambda^k*e^{-\lambda})/k!$

> $((0.1*40)^5*\exp(-0.1*40))/(5*4*3*2*1)$

[1] 0.1562935

> dpois(5,4)

[1] 0.1562935

Can anybody help me review my result?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Write your questions clearly. Please use MathJax . See  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no work was shown by the author.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not quite correct. Given that inter-arrival times are distributed $\mathrm{Exp(0.1)}$ and (presumably) independent, the number of arrivals in $40$ minutes follows a Poisson distribution with mean $4$, which seems to match what you have.

You now need the probability that *at least* five people arrive within this time. However, you appear to have worked out the probability that *exactly* $5$ arrive within this time.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{N(t):t\geqslant 0\}$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda>0$. Let $m$ be a positive integer and $T>0$ a fixed time. Then the probability that the first $m$ customers arrive during the first $T$ minutes is
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(N(T)\geqslant m) &= 1 - \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \mathbb P(N(T)= k)\\
&= 1 - \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} e^{-\lambda T}\frac{(\lambda T)^k}{k!}\\
&= 1-\frac{\Gamma (m,T \lambda )}{\Gamma (m)}\\
&= 1 - \frac{\int_T^\infty t^{m-1}e^{-t}\ \mathsf dt}{(m-1)!}.
\end{align}
Substituting in $\lambda = \frac1{1/10}$, $m=5$ and $T=40$, this reduces to
$$
1-\frac{3232241203}3e^{-400} \approx 1.
$$